# Finding the limit of this function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{m^{n}}{e^{n}n^{\frac12}} = 0$$ if $|m|\lt 1$, otherwise the limit is $\infty.$

How can I show that it converges if $|m|\lt 1?$

Comment: Not true, $|m|<e$ is sufficient for the convergence to $0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{m^{n}}{e^{n}n^{\frac12}}.$ Then $|a_n|^{1/n} \to \frac{|m|}{e}.$

Hence, if $|m|<e$, the series $ \sum a_n$ converges, thus $a_n \to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $|m| \leq e$ you have $\left|\frac{m^n}{e^n}\right| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mid a/b\mid^n$ converges if $\mid a/b\mid \lt 1$. In your case $\mid m/e\mid \lt 1$ or $\mid m\mid\lt e$.